A string of countries (some don't exist!)
The two countries you see can be replaced by other countries, but the two "?'s" can't. Which two countries must replace the question marks? Explain your reasoning.

|SOLOMONISLANDS ??SOUTHAFRICA  |


The knowledge required is basic, just need to do some googling to make sure.

The countries are

 SWEDEN AND LITHUANIA

Why

 The countries on the puzzle contain the first three letters as a string of a day of the week in order. The blanks represents no countries with the days of the week that have that three letter string; no countries contains TUE, SAT or SUN. SOLOMON ISLANDS can be replaced by MONACO and SOUTH AFRICA can be replaced by CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC.


Correct, those are the countries!

Also rot13(Zbatbyvn naq Zbagrarteb) :)

For the elderly amongst us rot13(Xvatqbz bs Cvrqzbag-Fneqvavn) :-)
